# Why is a private property part of the interface?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following:

```
class X  {
    bar() {
        return "bar"
    }
    constructor(private readonly x: number){}
}

interface Y extends X {
}


const f = (y: Y) => { console.log(y.bar()); }

f({ bar: () => "tavern"});
```

It does not compile, because `x` is missing.

```
f({ bar: () => "tavern", x: 1});
```

does not compile because `x` isn't private.

Re-writing the code so it's possible to declare the `x` private

```
class Y implements X {
    bar() {
        return "tavern"
    }
    private x = 1;
}
```

is rejected because "types have separate declarations".

The only solution I have found is to remove the `private` from the constructor.

What I'd really like to do is the first: I don't care about private properties of the class, and I especially don't care about private members declared within the constructor.

My two questions are:

1. Why is this the case?
2. What, if anything, can I do so I don't have to worry about private properties?

Comment: private class members were implemented in TypeScript long ago in way that required them to be considered for type compatibility, see explanation in [this issue comments](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18499#issuecomment-329842291)

Comment: @artem — if you'd like to promote this comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I think your question asks for more than that comment addresses, you could answer it yourself and describe how that particular problem could be solved

Comment: @artem — I actually did figure out a satisfactory solution!  See below.

Comment: the simplest solution is to not make it private.

Comment: @AluanHaddad — that isn't simple: I then have to actually implement that property (which accomplishes nothing) on the mock.

Comment: `Partial<>` does not guarantee that the `bar()` method is set.  `Public` (my invention) does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ryan Cavanaugh, development lead for the Typescript team at Microsoft, [wrote](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18499#issuecomment-329842291):

> Allowing the private fields to be missing would be an enormous
>   problem, not some trivial soundness issue.
>
> Consider this code:
>
> ```
> class Identity {
>   private id: string = "secret agent";
>   public sameAs(other: Identity) {
>     return this.id.toLowerCase() === other.id.toLowerCase();
>   }
> }
>
> class MockIdentity implements Identity {
>   public sameAs(other: Identity) { return false; }
> }
> ```
>
> `MockIdentity` is a public-compatible version of `Identity` but
>   attempting to use it as one will crash in `sameAs` when a non-mocked 
>   copy interacts with a mocked copy.

Which sucks.  It makes perfect sense, but it sucks.

**But** I found a workaround that solves my problem:

```
type Public<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P];
};

class X  {
    bar() {
        return "bar"
    }
    constructor(private readonly x: number){}
}

interface Y extends Public<X> { }

const f = (y: Y) => { console.log(y.bar()); }

f({ bar: () => "tavern"});
```

This allows me to mock out complex types reliably, without having to also mock out private data.

This is safe *in a test context*, where mocked instances and real instances never interact.

Comment: I was a bit amused by this example because `other.id` can be accessed, but here is the [TS doc explanation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#cross-instance-private-access) that it was a design decision.